# Python Anaconda - How to Safely Uninstall

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Python Anaconda on Mac (OS Mavericks). I wanted to revert to the default version of Python on my Mac. What's the best way to do this? Should I delete the `~/anaconda` directory? Any other changes required?

Currently when I run `which python` I get this path:

`/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: @PeterWang conda can't deploy on AWS, I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work and also can't use pip/virtualenv when I have anaconda installed...

Comment: Anaconda actually have a guide for uninstalling
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/full.html#os-x-anaconda-install

Comment: @PeterWang Anaconda overrites my default mac interpreter which by default is used by pip for module installs.  I wasted about an hour of my time today trying to figure out why my modules weren't being loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos)

Comment: how does one uninstall conda if in addition it cannot find the conda command but the directory still exists?

Answer (score 306):

From the [docs](https://conda.io/docs/install/full.html#os-x-anaconda-install):

> To uninstall Anaconda open a terminal window and remove the entire
>   anaconda install directory: `rm -rf ~/anaconda`. You may also edit
>   `~/.bash_profile` and remove the anaconda directory from your `PATH`
>   environment variable, and remove the hidden `.condarc` file and
>   `.conda` and `.continuum` directories which may have been created in
>   the home directory with `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`.

Further notes:

- Python3 installs may use a `~/anaconda3` dir instead of `~/anaconda`.
- You might also have a `~/.anaconda` hidden directory that may be removed.
- Depending on how you installed, it is possible that the `PATH` is modified in one of your runcom files, and not in your shell profile. So, for example if you are using bash, be sure to check your `~/.bashrc` if you don't find the `PATH` modified in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, the $PATH changes were made in `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Also `~/.anaconda/navigator`. It sure does splatter the directories around.

Comment: I had ~/anaconda3 for a python3 install.

Comment: my installation is at /anaconda3/, so some might need to do `rm -rf /anaconda3/`

Comment: Very helpful. As stated above  by canada11, I had anaconda2 so I had tu adjust the path accordingly

Comment: Also, `rm ~/.bashrc-anaconda3.bak`

Comment: Actually, depending on how lont time ago you installed anaconda, you might want to keep the `~/.bashrc-*.bak` since its the .bashrc before anaconda changes....

Answer (score 152):

The anaconda installer adds a line in your `~/.bash_profile` script that prepends the anaconda bin directory to your `$PATH` environment variable. Deleting the anaconda directory should be all you need to do, but it's good housekeeping to remove this line from your setup script too.

Comment: When I go to remove the anaconda directory I get some warnings: override rwxr-xr-x  root/staff for anaconda//bin/cftp - Okay to proceed with these? Also will python then automatically revert to the system install after removing anaconda and making bash changes?

Comment: Yep that should be fine. See [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#uninstall-anaconda) for the official word on this.

Comment: There may also be `~/.continuum` and `~/.spyder2` and `~/.cache` and `~/.distlib` and `~/.matplotlib` directories, which you should also delete.

Comment: In your home directory (`~/`), there is also a backup file created by anaconda: `.bash_profile-anaconda.bak`, which backup your original `.bash_profile`. You can compare that file with your current `.bash_profile`, and after that, you can safely remove the `.bash_profile-anaconda.bak` file.

Comment: I found anaconda's `$PATH` appending line in `~/.bashrc`, fyi.

Comment: removing .conda, .condarc, ~/anaconda2 and removing the addition to .bashrc worked for me to uninstall anaconda2 so far...

Comment: is adding it to the trash bin considered deleting

Comment: Where do I find his file bash file on windows?

Comment: @MohitMotwani on windows there is no bash file The steps are totally different for windows. [see here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Answer (score 134):

**Package** "**anaconda clean**", available from Anaconda platform, should uninstall safely.

```
conda activate your_conda_env  # activate your conda environment
conda install anaconda-clean   # install the package anaconda clean
anaconda-clean --yes           # clean all anaconda related files and directories 

rm -rf ~/anaconda3             # removes the entire anaconda directory

rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup       # anaconda clean creates a back_up of files/dirs, remove it 
                                # (conda list; cmd shouldn't respond after the clean up)
```

**Refer**: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall for more details.

**Note**: Also, you may want to edit .bashrc (or .bash_profile) & remove the conda path in $PATH environment variable for full proper clean-up

Comment: I had a second installation of anaconda via brew. To uninstall it I needed to call `brew cask uninstall anaconda` in addition.

Comment: Using this answer I lost my PATH and had to reset it. Wasn't a big issue seeing as mine's a brand new machine with no customised PATH (yet)... but wanted to comment in order to warn anyone who risks losing some import PATH configuration.

Answer (score 25):

Removing the Anaconda directory helps, but I don't think that's a good idea as you might need to use anaconda sometimes in near future. So, as suggested by [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom), anaconda installer automatically adds `PATH` variable which points to `anaconda/bin` directory in the `~/.bashrc` file.

It looks like this

```
PATH="/home/linuxsagar/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

So, just comment out the line (add `#` in the beginning of the line).
Then reload the `~/.bashrc` file executing `source ~/.bashrc`

Now, verify the changes executing `which python` in the new terminal.

Comment: @XiaodongQi have you tried `$which python` in new terminal window after `$source ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: I did check the path of python, it was still pointing to the anaconda directory. Then I found a workaround to solve this problem. Besides what you recommended, I also added a line `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` in the `~/.bashrc` file. It works afterward! Thanks!

Comment: Where do I find his file bash file on windows?

Answer (score 15):

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

It was pretty easy. It switched my pointer to Python:
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#os-x-uninstall

Answer (score 12):

### Install the cleaner

```
me@host:~$ conda install anaconda-clean
```

### Activate the 'base' virtual environment

```
me@host:~$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

### Run the cleaner

```
(base) me@host:~$ anaconda-clean --yes
```

### Deactivate the 'base' virtual environment

```
(base) me@host:~$ conda deactivate
```

### Remove the files

```
me@host:~$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3
me@host:~$ rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
```

### Delete lines added by conda from environment file(s)

Open the `.bashrc` file (and/or `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile`)

```
nano .bashrc
```

Search for `conda`:

1. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. type `conda`
3. press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Remove everything that looks like it has been added by/for anaconda:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/me/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/me/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

This was done on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: As a last step uninstall the cleaner?

Answer (score 10):

If you're uninstalling Anaconda to be able to use the base Python installation in the system, you could temporarily disable the path by following these steps and not uninstalling Anaconda.

Go to your home directory. Just a `cd` command will do.

Edit the file `.bashrc`.

Look for something like `export PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` in the file.

Put a `#` at the beginning to comment it from the script.

```
#export PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Open a new terminal and you should be running the base python installation. This works on Linux systems. Should work on Mac too.

Comment: for some reason, I had to restart. Don't think that's really necessary, but it worked w/o uninstalling anything.

Comment: yeah.. I don't think it's necessary! Just opening a new shell should do the job I reckon!

Answer (score 7):

## Uninstalling Anaconda

To uninstall Anaconda, you can do a simple remove of the program. This will leave a few files behind, which for most users is just fine. See Option A.

If you also want to remove all traces of the configuration files and directories from Anaconda and its programs, you can download and use the Anaconda-Clean program first, then do a simple remove. See Option B.

### Option A.

Use simple remove to uninstall Anaconda:

macOS–Open the Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application, and then remove your entire Anaconda directory, which has a name such as anaconda2 or anaconda3, by entering `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`.

### Option B.

Full uninstall using Anaconda-Clean and simple remove.

NOTE: Anaconda-Clean must be run before simple remove.

Install the Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt or a terminal window:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

In the same window, run one of these commands:

Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories with a confirmation prompt before deleting each one:

```
anaconda-clean
```

Or, remove all Anaconda-related files and directories without being prompted to delete each one:

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Anaconda-Clean creates a backup of all files and directories that might be removed, such as `.bash_profile`, in a folder named `.anaconda_backup` in your home directory. Also note that Anaconda-Clean leaves your data files in the AnacondaProjects directory untouched.
After using Anaconda-Clean, follow the instructions above in Option A to uninstall Anaconda.
Removing Anaconda path from `.bash_profile`

If you use Linux or macOS, you may also wish to check the `.bash_profile`file in your home directory for a line such as:

```
export PATH="/Users/jsmith/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

NOTE: Replace `/Users/jsmith/anaconda3/` with your actual path.

This line adds the Anaconda path to the PATH environment variable. It may refer to either Anaconda or Miniconda. After uninstalling Anaconda, you may delete this line and save the file.

by [official uninstalling way](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall)

Comment: installing something to uninstall something else? What? Now, how do I uninstall anaconda-clean? :|

Answer (score 7):

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3

nano ~/.bashrc
```

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to search for "Anaconda"
- Delete or comment out the following lines:

  ```
  /home/sammuel/.bashrc
  # added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
  export PATH="/home/sammuel/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
  ```

When you’re done editing the file, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit and <kbd>y</kbd> to save changes.

Anaconda is now removed from your server.

Comment: Also after deleting anaconda3 from the PATH, you need to run `source ~/bashrc` to make the changes effective on the current session.

Answer (score 3):

I simply:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

...this removed conda also.

Then:

```
mousepad ~/.bashrc
```

...and removed the path line added at the very bottom (clearly identified by Anaconda as 'added by Anaconda'.

Worth noting that anaconda3 created a backup of my **.bashrc** file before modification, and named it as:

```
./bashrc-anaconda3.bak
```

...so I could always have just renamed this and deleted my modified .bashrc

Answer (score 3):

In case you have multiple version of anaconda,

**rm -rf ~/anaconda2 [for version 2]**

**rm -rf ~/anaconda3 [for version 3]**

Open .bashrc file in a text editor

*vim .bashrc*

remove anaconda directory from your PATH.

**export PATH="/home/{username}/anaconda2/bin:$PATH" [for version 2]**

**export PATH="/home/{username}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" [for version 3]**

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall anaconda you have to:

1) Remove the entire anaconda install directory with:

`rm -rf ~/anaconda2`

2) And (OPTIONAL):

->Edit ~/.bash_profile to remove the anaconda directory from your PATH environment variable.

->Remove the following hidden file and folders that may have been created in the home directory:

`rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`

[source](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I always try to follow the developers advice, since they are usually the ones that now how it would affect your system. Theoretically this should be the safest way:

Install the Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt (terminal on Linux or macOS):

> `conda install anaconda-clean`

In the same window, run **one of these** commands:

1. Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories with a confirmation prompt before deleting each one:

> `anaconda-clean`

2. Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories without being prompted to delete each one:

> `anaconda-clean --yes`

Anaconda-Clean creates a backup of all files and directories that might be removed in a folder named .anaconda_backup in your home directory. Also note that Anaconda-Clean leaves your data files in the AnacondaProjects directory untouched.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall Anaconda Fully from your System :

1. Open Terminal
2. `rm -rf ~/miniconda`
3. `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`

Answer (score 1):

In my case Anaconda3 was not installed in home directory. Instead, it was installed in root. Therefore, I had to do the following to get it uninstalled:

```
sudo rm -rf /anaconda3/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

In the same window, run one of these commands:
TO remove all Anaconda-related files and directories without being prompted to delete each one:

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Windows:

Use Windows Explorer to delete the envs and pkgs folders prior to running the uninstall in the root of your installation.

In the Control Panel, choose Add or Remove Programs or Uninstall a program, and then select Python 3.6 (Anaconda) or your version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

In macOs
`rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3`

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

It was enough

Answer (score 0):

For windows

- Install anaconda-clean module using

  ```
  conda install anaconda-clean
  ```

  then, run the following command to delete files step by step:

  ```
  anaconda-clean
  ```

  Or, just run following command to delete them all-

  ```
  anaconda-clean --yes
  ```
- After this Open Control Panel> Programs> Uninstall Program, here uninstall that python for which publisher is Anaconda.
- Now, you can remove anaconda/scripts and /anaconda/ from PATH variable.

Hope, it helps.