# How to removing anaconda from Ubuntu completely

Tags: python, linux, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda

I installed Python Anaconda a while ago, but I had some problems using certain software so I had to remove the directory where it was installed

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

but now I am having some problems with others softwares, like cmake, when I execute *make* I obtain the next error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/delfin/anaconda/lib/libQtOpenGL.so', needed by `exampleB1'.  Stop.
```

but I don't have anymore that directory. How can I remove and restore all the configuration installed in my system by Anaconda. I tried the next command to see where it was the information stored

```
grep -rnw '/home/delfin'  -e "anaconda"
```

but there are many files that contain that string, and I don't want to spoil anything, I would aprecciate any ideas, thanks

Comment: `conda uninstall anaconda` maybe? http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-uninstall.html

Comment: Did you remove the export from your .bashrc file?

Comment: when I execute `conda uninstall anaconda` I get `conda: command not found`, and yes, I removed the export from .bashrc ... I don't know if it is something related with qt, but I have already uninstall it and reinstall it

Comment: Maybe you want to reinstall it, then remove it using conda?

Comment: Do you get any output as a result to executing: "grep -i conda ~/.basrc" and "grep -i conda ~/.profile" ?

Comment: with `grep -i conda ~/.bashrc` I get nothing, but with `grep -i conda ~/.profile` I get
`# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/delfin/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` maybe is that, I am going to check

Comment: You see the error when you execute "make" on a specific makefile, can you please check that the makefile doesn't include any reference to "anaconda"? please try to find the reference to "exampleB1"

Comment: I removed the export from .profile but I still get the same error,  the anaconda references are in a file called _build.make_  but I don't know how I should replace them

Comment: What is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If the anaconda installation directory is removed and it's gone from your PATH then it is probably fully uninstalled.  Was this "build.make" auto-generated before you removed anaconda? Is there a ./configure script associated with this project? You might want to run that again.

Comment: This has some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall