# Reset python path after Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, anaconda

I used IDLE for some time, then for a class they told us to download Anaconda, which I ended up not using, but still downloaded it anyway. 
I uninstalled anaconda and deleted all the files from my CPU and started using IDLE again. I now can't import a module to IDLE because it can't find it. I think anaconda messed up the python path, but I don't know how to change it so I can import modules back to python.

How can I determine what the python path is and how can I change it so when I download modules I can import them to IDLE again?

I am running OsX 10.10.5 and Python 2.7.10.

Comment: To find your python path, open terminal and type `echo $PYTHONPATH`. You can edit it in your `.bash_profile` file (in your user library).

Answer (score 1):

To add the python path for anaconda if you are on windows:

1. Right click my computer
2. Go to advanced settings
3. Click on environment variables
4. Find the PATH variable and click edit
5. Add the path where your python.exe file is located

Example:
C:\Anaconda3 - might not work
C:\Anaconda3 - then this should work

Same thing for those, who have other installations.

Answer (score 0):

Like @lsxliron mentioned in his comment you should probably check your `.bash_profile` and make sure that anaconda isn't in your `PATH`.  It should have added itself there during the installation.

You might also want to confirm that IDLE isn't still pointing to the anaconda python that you've now removed.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) for more details on uninstalling anaconda on OS X.

Comment: Try removing `export PATH="/Users/HenryFroland/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`and then source your bash profile (i.e. probably `source ~/.bash_profile`. I'm not very familiar with macs, sorry.).