# Issues Uninstalling Anaconda and Pythonpath

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm trying to uninstall Anaconda (the why doesn't matter). Using this article: [Python Anaconda - How to Safely Uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall), but it appears I'm having different issues.

I used `rm -rf ~/anaconda`, entered `python3` in my terminal and get: `-bash: /Users/myuser/anaconda/bin/python3: No such file or directory`

It looks like my python path is incorrect. Looking at this comment: export https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377981/994558, I used `nano ~/.bashrc` but that files doesn't exist.

I'm confused because `which python` gives me: `/usr/bin/python`

Any help?

Comment: looks like you had somehow activated a virtualenv and then deleted it. Can you try in a new terminal.

Comment: That does it! So simple, appreciate it.