# Trouble running new Python version after uninstalling older and installing new (MAC)

Tags: python, bash, macos, anaconda, python-install

I was trying to uninstall my Anaconda version of Python and reinstall the regular Python 3.5 version (mac). I used the answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) to remove the Anaconda folder using `rm -rf ~/anaconda` and using the Python website installed version 3.5.

But running `python --version` or `python` from command line returns this error:

```
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ paul$ python --version
-bash: /Users/paul/anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Is there some bash script that is pointing the old deleted /Anaconda folder that is causing the 3.5 version to not run? I really don't want to mess with system files if I don't know what I'm doing

Comment: What happens when you run `which python`?

Comment: @SpruceBondera /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: What about `type python`?

Comment: python is hashed (/Users/paulgerhartz/anaconda/bin/python)

Comment: Try `hash -d python`. That should fix it, however you should then try restarting bash and seeing if the incorrect entry is being added on startup.

Comment: `hash -d python` worked! Didn't even have to restart. Thank you so much. You can post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems like bash has stored `/Users/paul/anaconda/bin/python` as the entry for `python` for performance reasons. `hash -d python` should remove this entry and use normal path resolution.