# Error with Python after I Uninstalled Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.6 and just uninstalled Anaconda following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall).  I downloaded Python 3.5.2 from python.org and installed that version but in the terminal when I type in python it responds with the following:

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Also when I try to install pip via the terminal using the command 'sudo easy_install pip' I get the following response:

Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.2
Processing pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
pip 8.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.  I'm just want to be able to use the Python IDLE from python.org

Thanks

Comment: `pip` is installed with Anaconda.   You can see the collection of packages installed with Anaconda using `conda list` at the terminal

Comment: Try `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: @James python3 works when I enter that in terminal but when I enter conda list it says '-bash: conda: command not found'

Comment: @bryan That's because you uninstalled Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDLE should already be bundled with the standard Python installation on OS X, so just type `idle` in a Terminal window and it should start up.  This should work even when you have Anaconda (or Miniconda) installed.

Personally, I have Miniconda installed and I can still run `idle`.

However, IDLE is arguably inferior to a number of alternatives, such as Spyder, which comes with Anaconda, and PyCharm, which I prefer and use almost exclusively.

Have you tried running `idle` from a Terminal window? If so, and you get an error, what is it?

Comment: idle from a Terminal window works and starts up the Python 3.5.2 shell.  But when I try to install pip from terminal I get the error 'error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'

Comment: I imagine something got fouled up with the install and uninstall of Anaconda that is now preventing `pip` from being found. However, given that your post said that you just want to be able to use `idle` and you just indicated that you can indeed do so, you may wish to mark this a solution and open a separate question regarding your problem with `pip`.

It's much easier for people to help with your questions/issues when you don't list multiple in a posting. It also makes it easier for others having the same question/issue to find answers.

Comment: I have some suggestions regarding your problem with `pip`, but given my previous comment, I suggest you mark this as solved, open a new question, and I'd be happy to post suggestions regarding `pip` there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Will do