# Python Anaconda Uninstall - How to remove Python Anaconda custom (x86_64)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to completely uninstall Anaconda from my Mac OS X (El Capitan), and I have followed all the instructions in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall), but my python still seems to be using the 'Anaconda custom' python, which I think I have installed through Anaconda.

I have already removed anaconda directory using `rm -rf ~/anaconda`, and I have removed all other related dotfiles like .anaconda, .conda, .continuum, and etc. I also followed `conda install anaconda-clean` and `anaconda-clean --yes`, and erased the .anaconda_backup as well. I also have checked both .bash_profile and .bashrc, but there were no anaconda related PATH.

But, when I type `python -V` on shell, I still get `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)` for its version.

I looked up the pythons in my /usr/bin directory and there seem to have many different python versions existing like python 2.6, python2.7, python2.7-config, etc... and I have no idea which one is the Anaconda custom python that I need to remove. Can anyone help me to remove this Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom?

Comment: you need to remove it from your bashrc too and i guess maybe you might have some kind of virtualenv too,virtualenv check the first python to appear in your path,if not found,they go for the second one

Comment: I checked both .bash_profile and .bashrc but they did not have any anaconda PATH. Would it be better to delete all python and reinstall it?

Comment: What do you get if you type `which python` in the shell?

Comment: I got `/Applications/anaconda/bin/python`! So, I deleted all anaconda files in Applications, but now if I type `python -V`, it says `-bash: /Applications/anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think my path for python is defined somewhere but I don't see where...