# pip : was OK for months now :ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

All ok until now; Using Win10, Anaconda dstribution, attempting to run pip leads to :

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py",
  line    from pip import main  
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init_    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mer    from pip.download import path_to_url  
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\downloa    from pip._vendor.requests.adapters import BaseAdapter, 
  H mportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\susen\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Users\susen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\susen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Users\susen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.adapters import BaseAdapter, HTTPAdapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'
```

This is happening since I upgraded some packages yesterday. Then I couldn't run pip whatsoever.

I ended up doing a **clean install of anaconda**. That solved the problem.

Comment: All right, almost the same issue appeared to me when launching a new virtual environment : `ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'
` even if it looked good in other environment. Did you uninstalled it first like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) ?

Comment: That link talks about macOS, I was running anaconda on Windows 10 and I just uninstalled it, didn't remove any folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested removing a request folder from lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor folder. github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6317

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
conda install pip -f
```