# changing conda default python version

Tags: python, anaconda

First, I already do

```
conda install python=3.6
```

and I know

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
source activate py36
```

But, what I want to change is default python version of anaconda in

platform : osx-64

```
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.19
     python version : 3.5.4.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : /Users/moonkeelee/anaconda  (writable)
default environment : /Users/moonkeelee/anaconda
   envs directories : /Users/moonkeelee/anaconda/envs
                      /Users/moonkeelee/.conda/envs
      package cache : /Users/moonkeelee/anaconda/pkgs
                      /Users/moonkeelee/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : None
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.5.4 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6    
            UID:GID : 501:20
```

As I said, I alreay do

```
conda install python=3.6
```

but, it did not change the version of conda python version as you see above. If I redo install python 3.6 the following error occurred

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
```

`- argcomplete -> argparse -> python 2.6*`

`- python 3.6*`

`Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

Now.. I don't know how to do it. The reason I want to change default version of python, not use conda's environment, I want to develop python with `atom`, and if I check the python version in `atom` with

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

the version always 3.5 although I installed python 3.6.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uninstall the offending package first. Sometimes there can be conflicts with older version packages ( or even those packages might not be supported in the newest python version, yet - this should not be case of arcomplete ).

`conda uninstall arcomplete`

- this is an alias for `conda remove argcomplete conda-manager`

and then run again

`conda install python=3.6`

If another conflicts pop up, I suggest removing conda from path and reinstalling it completely, it might be in a broken or conflict state from previous usage (e.g --force removal)

Comment: Yes... I did with your suggestion but not work. so I uninstall anaconda and install it. And it change (finally) the version of python with 3.6. I referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall and https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall. Anyway.. thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two python version in anaconda suppose 3.6 and 3.7 and you want to change the default version follow this step.

$ python --version 
Python 3.7.3
$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ alias python=python3.6
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9

Comment: `alias` command does not work in Windows.