# Anaconda, spyder and python path

Tags: python, path

I have an installation of python 3.6.2 on Windows 10 in :

```
D:\Program Files\Python36
```

I recently installed Anaconda, but I did not add the new version to the path, because I wanted to keep my installation and libraries.

On spyder (launch from Anaconda), in Tools, and PYTHONPATH gestionnary, I can see

[image]

with PATH being:

```
['C:\\Anaconda', 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin', 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\usr\\bin', 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin', 'C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts', '%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps']
```

Yet, if I start IDLE (old installation), I can import OpenCV (import cv2), but not from spyder.... How could I fix this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of python on your computer, so packages installed using your older version of `pip` won't show up for the anaconda installation.

Chances are you may want to keep both installs, so you could just install desired anaconda packages by running `conda install packageName` from your command prompt or terminal. However, these newly installed packages will only be available in anaconda/python, not your IDLE/python.

Comment: Anyway to delete the Anaconda part, and to keep my installation of python + the environment of spyder ?

Comment: Yes, you can uninstall anaconda and then install Spyder as its own IDE. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall and  https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html