# Python Terminal Invalid Syntax Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

Hello I am new to Stackflow so please bear with me on asking this question.

Earlier today, requests module did not work on my IDLE (3.6.5), and asked a question on reddit how to get it work. However, I followed a bad advice, and might have deleted some site-packages. (https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8xgx1p/no_module_named_requests/)

Now, I was able to recover from it and pip module is running fine. (e.g. If I tried running import requests on IDLE, it gives me no error). However, on Terminal, when I try to run commands such as "pip list", it gives me Invalid syntax error.

Could someone help a newbie out?

Comment: Please show exactly what you typed, and the exact error you got, rather than just describing it vaguely.

Comment: Also, are you typing `pip list` into the bash shell in your Terminal (at the prompt that looks like `jyabjyabs-macbook:myproj jyabjyabs$`), or did you run `python` in the terminal, and then try to type `pip list` inside Python (at the prompt that looks like `>>>`)? If the latter, that's your problem: `pip` is a command that you run at the shell, not a Python statement.

Comment: I am typing in terminal, where it says my user name jyabjyabs:~

Comment: The error Terminal gives me is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: I tried adding my executable which is (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6) infront of the command, but did not work.  It just gives me,   File "<stdin>", line 1
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6" -m pip install request
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: OK, is the Python installation you're trying to use an Anaconda one? And did you ever install two different Pythons on this machine (e.g., one from the python.org installer, and another from Anaconda)? Because it looks like you have a leftover `pip` command from a Python installation that you either uninstalled, or wiped clean.

Comment: (You _always_ have at least one extra Python on macOS, because Apple gives you a 2.7.10 version whether you want it or not. But that one isn't in `/anaconda3` or in `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6`, so it isn't the problem here.)

Comment: Also, it would really help if you could copy and paste each command—including the prompt, and the full error output—into your question, instead of just adding comments.

Comment: I am using IDLE 3.6.5 to run python...

Comment: But I do have anaconda on my laptop, but I am not using it at all

Comment: No, IDLE is just the IDE, not the Python installation. Each Python installation will have its own copy of IDLE.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am trying to provide as much information. How can I check which installation I'm using to run python? All I know is that I'm currently using IDLE to run python codes

Comment: I am currently learning through the book called "Automate the boring stuff with Python", and I remember downloading something from python,org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the error comes from `/anaconda3/bin/pip` means that you're running the `pip` command for your Anaconda installation, not the `pip` command for the other Python 3.6 installation you actually wanted to use (the one in `/Library/Frameworks/Python/Versions/3.6`).

I'm not sure how your Anaconda installation got broken, but if you don't want to use it, it may be easier to just [uninstall it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) than to try to fix it.

And that will also save you a lot of confusion in the future. Having multiple Python installations around can be useful, but if you don't have any useful for it, why give yourself the headaches?<sup>1</sup>

Meanwhile, because of all of that confusion, when you have, or might have, multiple Python installations, the recommended way to run `pip` is not just `pip`, but instead `python3 -m pip` or `python3 -m pip`, or `/Library/Frameworks/Python/Versions/3.6/bin/python -m pip`. Basically, whatever command you use to run Python itself, use that same command (with `-m pip` added) to run `pip`.

You might also want to consider [using a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/). Once you've activated an environment, everything will just work, no matter what other Python installations you have lying around.

---

<sub>1. Unfortunately, on macOS, there's a pre-installed Python 2.7 whether you want it or not, so you will have at least two Python versions. But you can usually avoid this by either making sure to use `python3`, `pip3`, etc. instead of the no-suffix versions, or using virtual environments. Also, if your main Python is a 3.x version, and you've installed it so that it doesn't need `sudo`, so you never use `sudo`, you can never accidentally install something into the Apple Python instead of the one you wanted—if you do, you'll get permission errors and nothing will get installed anywhere.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Uninstalling Anaconda Navigator, Anaconda3 files seemed to do the trick. Now I can run pip commands successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure pip is installed and added to your PATH.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/