# anaconda conda: error: argument command: invalid choice when trying to update packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I am using ubuntu 18 with anaconda for python 3.6 and trying to update packages, when I try to do so using

```
conda update --all
```

I am getting this error

> conda: error: argument command: invalid choice:
>   '/home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda'

I tried so solve it like explained in [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6171) github issue

using

```
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater
```

But getting the same error. 
I tried adding 
-c conda-forge to all the commands 
And tried using 
conda update anaconda 
conda upgrade anaconda

and getting the same error all the time.

Here is my github [issue](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-project/issues/175) on this

Thanks!

update: 
even when trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) to install anaconda-clean and removing anaconda, I am getting the same error when trying to install conda-clean that should help me remove anaconda from my machine

Comment: fixed it when removing the entire conda dir, and reinstalling from scratch, still don't know what's causing this. this is not the first time :-(

Comment: I have an Ubuntu x64 16.04 and I'm getting the same error...

Answer (score 45):

The issue of Conda yielding unexpected errors across different environments is well-known. Often, the default settings clash with one's own, or if self-configured, an incorrect path may have been set in one's shell configuration file (in my case, for instance, the `~/.zshrc` file).

One could meticulously analyze the causes, set the correct path, and then restart the shell (for `zsh`, this would be executed via `zsh -l`).

**Quick solution**

However, if you're in a hurry and wish to make all the necessary configurations later, a more expedient solution exists on Linux-based systems; you can simply try the following:

```bash
source activate <env-name>
```

**Understanding the issues**

Upon initializing Conda, it would also be prudent to specify the name of one's own shell, such as

```bash
conda init zsh
```

Subsequently, a list of system modifications will be displayed:

```bash
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified /Users/<username>/.zshrc # <--- ADDITONAL CHANGES
```

Upon inspection here, one would discover this entry.

```bash
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

After restarting one's own shell (as previously mentioned, with `zsh -l` where `-l` stands for load), the command

```bash
conda activate <env-name>
```

should then operate as desired.

**In conclusion, a brief summary:**

1. Initialisation

```bash
conda init <shell-name> # e.g., zsh or bash
```

2. Apply the changes by restarting the terminal.

If it is zsh, then

```bash
zsh -l
```

3. Create a new environment for a certain python version

```bash
conda create --name <env-name> python=3
```

4. Check if the environment is already created

```bash
conda env list
```

An example would be:

```bash
base                     /opt/homebrew/anaconda3
codellama             *  /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/codellama
llama2                   /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/llama2
```

The `*` indicates that `codellama` is currently active

5. Active the environment

```bash
conda activate <env-name>
```

This should function without any issues.

Comment: Thanks. `conda init zsh` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue, just run

```
conda init
```

Saved me after one whole hour of troubleshooting. Turns out my `C:\Users\**\miniconda3\Scripts\activate` and `C:\Users\**\miniconda3\Scripts\deactivate` weren't updated.

Answer (score 3):

Add this on top of your bash script:

```
source  ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Functions are not exported by default to be made available in subshells. See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980

Comment: added to ~/.bashrc
source  ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
points for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

For `Linux` users I actually found that deleting all the lines added by conda in the `.bashrc` other than `export PATH="/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
 to be the best solution for this.

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

Not sure it's a fix for everyone, but I got around this by running `/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/conda install anaconda-clean` (or wherever your conda file is stored), and from the packages this installed, the problem magically disappeared.

If that doesn't work, try doing a 'full' uninstall of anaconda (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/), reinstall it, then try doing what I suggested above.