# Cannot move a file with Dockerfile: mv: cannot stat package: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker

A Docker and Linux newbie over here -

I am trying to move a (mini)conda file using Dockerfile. I wrote the following minimal Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    g++


ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
RUN bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
RUN rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
RUN ~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
RUN conda init
RUN conda create -n myenv python=3.8
RUN echo "conda activate myenv" >> /etc/profile
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN cd ~
RUN wget https://roboti.us/download/mjpro150_linux.zip
RUN unzip mjpro150_linux.zip
RUN mkdir ~/.mujoco
RUN mv mjpro150 ~/.mujoco
RUN wget https://roboti.us/file/mjkey.txt
RUN mv mjkey.txt ~/.mujoco
RUN rm mjpro150_linux.zip

RUN cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/
RUN /bin/bash -c "mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old"
```

When I run it -

```
docker build -t tbd_image .
```

I get the following error -

```
 > [21/21] RUN /bin/bash -c "mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old":                                                                                                                                                
0.552 usage: conda [-h] [-v] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...                                                                                                                                                       
0.552 conda: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'content-trust', 'doctor', 'repoquery', 'env')
0.581 mv: cannot stat 'libstdc++.so.6': No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:38
--------------------
  36 |     
  37 |     RUN cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/
  38 | >>> RUN /bin/bash -c "mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old"
  39 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash --login -c /bin/bash -c \"mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

However, if I manually create a container and execute the command, it works perfect.

I went over similar posts from StackOverflow. However, they did not resolve my issue. I noticed one post saying that `bash` interprets `*` differently. But I don't see any `*` in my file.

Comment: Looks like there is no `libstdc++.so.6` in the current directory. Have you tried running a `ls` before the `mv`? Why are you starting a separate shell with `/bin/bash -c "mv ..."` instead of just calling `mv ...`?

Comment: `RUN cd ...` has no effect, and you're not in the directory you think you're in.  Also see [difference between RUN cd and WORKDIR in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847410/difference-between-run-cd-and-workdir-in-dockerfile).

Comment: @Turing85 Because of a similar SO post recommended it. Apparently, the user had `*` in their file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Change:

```
RUN cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/
RUN /bin/bash -c "mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old"
```

For:

```
RUN cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/ && mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
```

**More details:**

You have a few problems. The first one is here:

```
RUN conda create -n myenv python=3.8
```

This is interactive and expects a "y/n" answer. You can tell it to always answer "yes" by passing `-y` like this:

```
RUN conda create -y -n myenv python=3.8
```

Your second problem is that `conda init bash` added code to your `/root/.bashrc`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077188/2427955) for more details on this. That code is not being executed because you have the below:

```
RUN echo "conda activate myenv" >> /etc/profile
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
```

This makes all future `RUN` calls process `/etc/profile`, but without first processing `.bashrc` which is (now) needed for `conda` to work properly. That's why you are seeing all of those "usage" errors.

(The reason `.bashrc` isn't processed is because shells in `docker build` aren't interactive.)

To avoid that, just move those two lines (the profile update and setting `SHELL`) to the end of your file. The "usage" errors are probably harmless, though, as you aren't really relying on conda for anything else in this specific Dockerfile.

Finally, per "TL;DR" above, the (last) error you are having is because you shouldn't be using `cd` in a single `RUN` line. That changes the directory for that particular `RUN` command, but not for any subsequent command. Look into `WORKDIR` if you really need that, but also consider putting more commands into a single `RUN` to avoid several (arguably needless) intermediate images. More on that in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39330458/2427955).

Answer (score 1):

As David said in the comment, `RUN cd` is not performing what you want. You would need to use `WORKDIR` to achieve that, but you can't use shell expansion in the `WORKDIR` directive.

So, if you don't know the user in advance (and why it isn't just root? BTW), you can just simply replace the last `RUN` directive by this one, and remove the `RUN cd` directive which is doing nothing:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "mv /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/libstdc++.so.6.old"
```

Other options include performing the `cd` in the same shell as the copy:

```
RUN cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/ && bash -c "mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old"
```

Or even in the same bash command:

```
RUN  /bin/bash -c " cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/ && mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old"
```

But I also wonder why you are running that as a bash command at all when you could just do:

```
RUN  cd /$(whoami)/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/ && mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
```