# anaconda-navigator stuck on loading applications

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, macos-high-sierra

```
$ anaconda-navigator 
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/conda_api.py:1364: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  data = yaml.load(f)
2019-06-02 10:37:25,261 - ERROR download_api._get_url:416
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 539, in setup
self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 576, in post_setup
self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 169, in setup
self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 204, in set_applications
apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 888, in process_apps
versions=[vsdata.get('productVersion')],
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have seen this error posted in a few places but none of the sites give any viable solution.

The applications work if launched directly though (so for now, I'm going with that)

In case you need a detailed log, I have run the same command with --verbose and --debug options available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xump5Ns0FFX7N9Ujl0kqPZVNhXZgm4j1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating `anaconda` solved this issue for me in Manjaro

use `conda update anaconda-navigator` command to Update

Comment: wow, I don't remember the situation where I got this issue now. I have changed job and can't even reproduce it now since I don't use anaconda anymore

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution for freezing at `"Loading applications"`. 
Try to change the file at
`anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py`
in function `load_rc` from

```
data = yaml.full_load(f) # around line 1391
```

to

```
data = yaml.safeload(f)  # quoting from Salim Tekin
```

Comment: In windows 10 i had to install anaconda 5.2 for a tutorial. This solution pointed me in the right direction, my file however had:

```data = yaml.load(f)```

I changed it to:
```data = yaml.full_load(f)```

And this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try the solution given by **limkin092** in the link below:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10461

It worked for me just fine.

Comment: I did read about it in another thread but in that case the error continued to appear and hence I hadn't considered it. I'll give it a shot in any case

Comment: You should try reinstalling anaconda first and then try that procedure. To safely remove your current installation, refer to Surya in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235

Comment: The line number is now 1391 and the original code is now `data = yaml.full_load(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the navigator as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For me on windows 10, It worked with below steps

1. tasklist | findstr "pythonw"  ( shows Process IDs)
2. taskkill /pid 99999  /f  ( 99999 - is the PID of the process,kill all such process )
3. changed the below line
   C:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py at line 1364
   data = yaml.load(f)   ( old one
   data = yaml.safeload(f)  ( new line)
4. start anaconda navigator from start menu

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall a standalone version of python first. Once I did, then the install worked and the navigator launched fine.