# Pip3 NOT installing with python3, unusual case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install pip3. I ran `brew install python3` which installed python3 correctly. I also ran `brew post install python3` as I found on this site.

Now, I enter `which pip3`
and get `/usr/local/bin/pip3`

And when I run `pip3`
I get this message: `-bash: /anaconda3/bin/pip3: No such file or directory`

How do I completely remove anaconda from my computer AND install pip3 from here? I deleted the anaconda application, removed the PATH from nano ~/.bash_profile. and emptied the trash

EDIT: FIXED USING hash -r

Comment: Does your .bashrc contains something that adds anaconda to the path or some sort of alias of pip3?

Comment: Not sure, what should I look for?

Comment: Any line with "anaconda" in it, don't delete it yet though. Also, you may want to checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall

Comment: Nano ~/bashrc show a blank file

Comment: `~/.bashrc` don't forget the dot

Answer (score 1):

Waiting on my rep to hit 50.

Maybe an answer:

what is the output of? Checking to see if its a link

```sh
ls -la /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

Also look at your path

```sh
export | grep PATH
```

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 [Redacted]  admin  31 Jun 15 21:08 /usr/local/bin/pip3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/pip3

Comment: ls -la ../Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/pip3 , return anything?

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Explains why it cant run pip3, maybe need to check if pip3 is in different path

Comment: Yes, when I run pip3 I get /anaconda3/bin/pip3 No such file or directory, and I am trying to solve the issue of it being on the anaconda3 path

Answer (score 1):

are you running pip install command in conda environment

If  you are  running  it  in conda environment First deactivate it

Use

```
source deactivate
```

Comment: How do I tell which environment I am running It in?

Comment: Read this for info on conda environment   https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html