# Why is bash still searching for conda?

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda, conda

I have a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on it. Also, I have installed Anaconda python distribution. 
So, I was facing this Invalid archive error (similar to this [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8923)) after installing [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) (I am not sure whether it caused the error). After trying a lot to fix the issue, I finally gave up. I thought it was best to uninstall Anaconda. I have tried to follow the steps as in [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) (option B). But it just got stuck. Hence, I stopped the process.
After this, I tried option A [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)
(My .bash_profile file does not exist `bash: /home/tejas/.bash_profile: No such file or directory`).
But when I type 'conda' in the terminal, I get

```
bash: /home/tejas/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

indicating that that bash is still trying to find conda?

Additionally, I followed any extra commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall).

Edit 1: .bash_aliases is empty.

```
bash: /home/tejas/.bash_aliases: No such file or directory
```

Edit 2: result of 'type -a conda '
'''

```
conda is a function
conda () 
{ 
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA;
    else
        \local cmd="$1";
        shift;
        case "$cmd" in 
            activate | deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
            ;;
            install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall)
                OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${OLDPATH}";
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate;
                else
                    return $t1;
                fi
            ;;
            *)
                OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${OLDPATH}";
                return $t1
            ;;
        esac;
    fi

}
```

'''

My `./bashrc` is as follows:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash- 
doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
 case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the 
history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt 
below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; 
turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal 
window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and 
such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
 fi

 if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\ 
    [\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
 else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
 fi
 unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
   test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval 
"$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export 


GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01: 
quot e=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'   
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo 
terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0- 
9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
fi

export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
export PATH=$GOPATH:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Edit 3:

```
tejas@tejasHP:~$ grep -F 'CONDA_EXE' ~/.[!.]*
grep: /home/tejas/.adobe: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.anaconda: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.atom: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.cache: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.compiz: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.config: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.dbus: Permission denied
grep: /home/tejas/.dropbox: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.dropbox-dist: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gconf: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gimp-2.8: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gnome: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gnome2: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gnome2_private: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.gnupg: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.hplip: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.ipython: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.java: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.julia: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.jupyter: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.keras: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.lastpass: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.local: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.macromedia: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.matlab: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.mozilla: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.npm: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.nv: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.nx: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.oracle_jre_usage: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.pki: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.pypar2: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.pyxbld: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.qt: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.ssh: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.subversion: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.thumbnails: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.thunderbird: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.vim: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.vscode: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.xchat2: Is a directory
grep: /home/tejas/.zoom: Is a directory
```

Comment: Nothing in your `.bashrc` but it pulls in `.bash_aliases`; do you have an alias for `conda` there?

Comment: @tripleee bash: /home/tejas/.bash_aliases: No such file or directory

Comment: @tripleee: Aliases can be defined anywhere, in a file sourced directly or indirectly by `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, or entered manually. `type -a conda` will tell you directly how bash *thinks* the `conda` command is defined.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388923/why-is-this-question-considered-to-be-about-about-general-computing-hardware-and)

Comment: I would suggest to fix your bash configuration trough trial and error. The best thing you can do is **(1)** make a copy of your .bashrc and .bash_profile files to a safe place **(2)** empty the original files **(3)** Restart bash as a login shell (`bash -l`) 
 this will read the empty configuration files **(4)** check if the problem persists **(5)** if so, bash is **not** the problem **(6)** If the problem is gone, slowly feed in lines of the copied configuration files and restart the process until you find the line that creates the problem. **(7)** fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alias or shell function that invokes `/home/tejas/anaconda3/bin/conda` is one possible explanation. Try this:

```
type -a conda
```

which will tell you how the shell resolves the `conda` command.

If that comes up empty, the problem is probably in the way bash hashes command paths, so it doesn't have to search your `$PATH` every time you type a command. Bashes internal hash table can get out of sync with reality if you remove a command.

Try this:

```
hash conda
```

That will search `$PATH` for a `conda` command, and if it doesn't find it it will remove the hash entry. After that, typing `conda` should give you the usual `conda: command not found` error.

NOTE: `type -a conda` will probably cause bash to recheck the location of the `conda` command, and remove it from its internal hash table if it isn't found. So this could both diagnose and fix the problem.

UPDATE: The question has been updated, showing that there's a shell function called `conda`. The anaconda installation must have created something that defines that function, and it still exists in your running shell process. You probably also have some relevant environment variables still set, like `$CONDA_EXE`.

Removing the script that defines the functions and environment variables won't remove them from your running shell process.

If you start a new shell, it probably won't have those definitions (though if you invoke it from your current shell it will inherit any environment variables).

If you want to remove the function definition in your running shell process, you can do `unset conda`.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson please see the edit 2. Hash conda just returned me to the prompt. Typing 'conda' still leads to 'bash: /home/tejas/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
'

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the function you still have defined is the cause of this particular error message, but it's not clear from your question where it is defined or how to remove it.

Maybe grep for `CONDA_EXE` in your home directory:

```
grep -F 'CONDA_EXE' ~/.[!.]*
```

If that doesn't reveal anything, perhaps similarly look for it in system files, probably in `/etc`. Eventually, reveal how you installed Conda and from where, and perhaps explain in more detail what exactly you did to uninstall it.

Comment: I think I  have explained how I uninstalled Anaconda in the question detail section. I installed anaconda by downloading the installer from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/